# Remove duplicates from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have the below table

| item | area | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | a | 10 |
| item 1 | b | 17 |
| item 2 | b | 20 |
| item 3 | a | 10 |
| item 2 | c | 8 |

I am looking to have a result in SQL as below (a unique item and a unique area):

| item | area a | area b | area c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | 10 | 17 | 0 |
| item 2 | 0 | 20 | 8 |
| item 3 | 10 | 0 | 0 |

i do have this query which not giving me what am looking for if the area has been changed or increased also its for 2 columns table not 3 columns:

```
select 
    item, 
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then area end) as area_1, 
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then area end) as area_2, 
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then area end) as area_3 
from (
    select A.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by item order by area) as seqnum 
    from A 
) A 
group by item;
```

Looking forwards to your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* you have a fixed list of areas, then no need for window functions ; you can explicitly filter on each individual value in `max()`.

Another fix to your query is to take the max of `qty` rather than of `area` (whose value is already filtered).

```
select item, 
    coalesce(max(case when area = 'a' then qty end), 0) as area_a,
    coalesce(max(case when area = 'b' then qty end), 0) as area_b, 
    coalesce(max(case when area = 'c' then qty end), 0) as area_c
from mytable 
group by item
```

Comment: you are right, my apology  it works perfectly even when I hard query it, appreciated your support